# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark covers cell separator on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview

Using this code on iOS 7 results in the separator view getting covered or shortened:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

How can I fix the separator view?

I'm using prototype cells, but I'm not subclassing them.

[image]

[EDIT]

Here is the relevant code from cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.section == kDefaultViewSection){
    NSArray *defaultViewNames = @[LQSettingsSentenceView, LQSettingsFullTextView, LQSettingsFlashcardsView];
    NSString *preferredViewName = [LQSettings valueForKey:LQSettingsPreferredLessonView];
    if ([defaultViewNames[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:preferredViewName]){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.section != kDefaultViewSection){
        return;
    }

    // Just turn all checks off for a minute
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:kDefaultViewSection];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;    
}
```

Comment: post your cellrowAtIndexPath and didselectedrow method

Comment: Sure.  Basically does what I put before.

Comment: Are you removing old subviews from cell before you reuse it ? Something like : if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) [subview removeFromSuperview];

Comment: @arsenius > Any luck?

Comment: @Rashad No.  In fact, I currently no longer even bother trying to use the system provided separators.

Answer (score 7):

In my case,I have disabled system-provided separator line and add my custom separator line in cell's xib.Sometimes the right checkmark covers the part of the bottom separator line.What I have done to solve the problem is that I have changed the trailing constraint to the `cell` instead of the `contentView`. [**Not the superview**]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable separator in the tableview and add subview a custom separator view at the bottom of the cell.

Comment: That's a workaround, but not really a proper fix.  I have a lot of cells I'd have to add that to in IB or subclass.  This really seems like a bug on apple's part.

Comment: Yes I know.. Even I had bumped into this issue. Finally resorted to the method I have mentioned. Please post if you find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a backgroundView on the UITableViewCell's `backgroundView` property. In that custom backgroundView add a separator line view that extends the full width of the view. The backgroundView is unaffected by the accessoryView.

> open var backgroundView: UIView?
>
> Default is nil for cells in UITableViewStylePlain, and non-nil for UITableViewStyleGrouped. The 'backgroundView' will be added as a subview behind all other views.

For example...

```
let separator = UIView()
separator.backgroundColor = .gray

let customBackgroundView = UIView()

customBackgroundView.addSubview(separator)
separator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

separator.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customBackgroundView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
separator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customBackgroundView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
separator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

backgroundView = customBackgroundView
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped. I ended up:

1. creating a custom class for UITableViewCell with ✓ as UILabel. You can also use UIImage.
2. Drag the IBOutlet to the custom class, I named it *checkMarkLabel*
3. Set up the constraints.
4. In the main viewController class, I declared a string property *selectedItem*
5. In **cellforrow** function,

   ```
    if selectedItem == tableData[indexPath.tow]{
        cell.checkMarkLabel.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.checkMarkLabel.isHidden = true
    }
   ```
6. In **didSelectRow** function,

   ```
    selectedItem = tableData[indexPath.tow]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
    }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Go to Xib or Storyboard, Select tableview and set separator style as single line.[image: Snapshot]